# Can I delete cloudagent folder?

Tags: dropbox, cloud

I have my dropbox files in the /storage/emulated/0/cloudagent folder. Can I delete this directory from my phone? Will it affect my files in my dropbox? 
Thank you!

Comment: Might be related to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46478/what-precisely-is-cloudagent-process-its-files-eats-space-like-crazy), but not sure.

Comment: Sync it to DropBox, then turn off sync, then delete the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cloudagent folder is used to sync imaged FROM your dropbox cloud account to your phone, so they are available in the image gallery.

If you are already syncing your phone to dropbox, then you will have 2 copies of each image on your phone - probably not what you meant.

You can delete the folder, but it will return later. You first need to disable cloud syncing - it is in settings -> cloud -> images (or something similar). Then you can delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files inside that folder. If the files contain no important data then the folder of safe to delete. I myself do not have such a folder and Dropbox is working fine.

Comment: They do contain important data. I want to have them in my dropbox, but not in my phone's internal memory.

Comment: Upload that folder to your Dropbox, then you can delete it because you backed it up.

Comment: But double check if the files contain the same information